# How to Show the result of a Query in a Grid Using ZK?

Tags: java, sql, sql-server-2008, zk

I new in ZK, i want to create a GRID with Rows of the result of a Query Stament.

This is my Code:

```
    <window title="REPORTE IMPRESION" border="normal">
    <zscript><![CDATA[
    import java.sql.*;
    void submit() {
        //load driver and get a database connetion
        Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
        Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(
                "jdbc:sqlserver://127.0.0.1;databaseName=Reports", "sa", "sa");
        PreparedStatement stmt = null;
        try {
            stmt = conn
                    .prepareStatement("select s.ID, s.NOMBRE, c.FECHA, c.PAG, c.TOTAL, c.PAG * 3.3 as TOTAL_PAGAR, c.PAG * 2.67 as Impresion, (c.PAG * 2.67)+(c.PAG * 3.3) as R FROM C_Sucursal s, Corte c where s.CLAVE=c.CLAVE and c.FECHA=?");

            //insert what end user entered into database table
            stmt.setString(1, fecha.getContext());
            //execute the statement and Put the result in a ResultSet
            PreparedStatement consulta1 = stmt;
            ResultSet result1 = consulta1.executeQuery();
            int  i=0;
            while(result1.next()){
                            //Here i need to put the result in a row! 
                System.out.println(result1.getObject(i));
                i++;
            }

        } finally { //cleanup
            if (stmt != null) {
                try {
                    stmt.close();
                } catch (SQLException ex) {
                    log.error(ex); //log and ignore
                }
            }
            if (conn != null) {
                try {
                    conn.close();
                } catch (SQLException ex) {
                    log.error(ex); //log and ignore
                }
            }
        }
    }
]]>
     </zscript>
    <div apply="org.zkoss.bind.BindComposer">
        <borderlayout sclass="complex-layout" height="580px">
            <north size="120px" border="0">
                <div>
                    <image sclass="complex-layout-header-img"
                        src="/images/bb.png" />
                </div>
            </north>
            <!-- Content -->
            <center>
                <div>
                    <hlayout>
                        <label sclass="hightlight">
                            Fecha del Corte
                        </label>
                    </hlayout>
                    <datebox id="fecha" width="150px"
                        format="dd-MM-yyyy" />
                    <button label="submit" onClick="submit()" />
                    <grid>
                        <columns menupopup="auto">
                            <column label="ID" sort="auto" />
                            <column label="SUCURSAL" sort="auto" />
                            <column label="PAGINAS" sort="auto" />
                            <column label="EDO_CUENTA" sort="auto" />
                            <column label="TOTAL A PAGAR" sort="auto" />
                            <column label="IMPRESION" sort="auto" />
                            <column label="ENVIO" sort="auto" />
                        </columns>
                    </grid>
                </div>
            </center>
            <south size="40px" border="0"
                style="background: none repeat scroll 0 0 ;">
                <toolbar mold="panel" align="center">
                    DERECHOS RESERVADOS
                </toolbar>
            </south>
        </borderlayout>
    </div>
</window>
```

How can put the result of the Query in the rows of the grid? Help!

I make a stament and the result is what i need to put in the rows, but i dont know how to put the result.

Answer (score 1):

Give your grid an id, pass it to your method and you can use the Grid object in your method (that you pass in) and create rows as necessary to display your data.

```
<grid id="myGrid">
  <columns menupopup="auto">
    <column label="ID" sort="auto" />
    <column label="SUCURSAL" sort="auto" />
    <column label="PAGINAS" sort="auto" />
    <column label="EDO_CUENTA" sort="auto" />
    <column label="TOTAL A PAGAR" sort="auto" />
    <column label="IMPRESION" sort="auto" />
    <column label="ENVIO" sort="auto" />
  </columns>
</grid>
```

When you call your function, pass in "myGrid" to it

```
submit(myGrid);
```

Let say, you have a private method that work to add the result to the grid for you, and say your result is wrapped in an object called "Data", the following will display the data in the grid:

```
private void displayResult(Grid myGrid, List<Data> data)
{

    Rows rows = new Rows();
    rows.setParent(programGrid);    

    for(Data d : data)
    {
        Label idLabel = new Label(d.getID());
        Label sucursalLabel = new Label(d.getSucursal());
        Label paginasLabel = new Label(d.getPaginas());
        .... etc ...

        Row row = new Row();    

        idLabel.setParent(row);
        sucursalLabel.setParent(row);
        paginasLabel.setParent(row);
        .... etc ...

        row.setParent(rows);
    }
}
```